# GPFS : mmremote: Unable to determine the local node identity

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, distributed, distributed-system

I had a 4 node, gpfs cluster up and running, and things were fine till last week when the Server hosting these RHEL setups went down, After the server was brought up and rhel nodes were started back, one of the nodes's IP got changed,

After that I am not able to use the node,

simple commands like 'mmlscluster', mmgetstate', fails with this error:

> [root@gpfs3 ~]# mmlscluster mmlscluster: Unable to determine the local
>   node identity. mmlscluster: Command failed. Examine previous error
>   messages to determine cause. [root@gpfs3 ~]# mmstartup mmstartup:
>   Unable to determine the local node identity. mmstartup: Command
>   failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.

Mmshutdown fails with different error:

> [root@gpfs3 ~]# mmshutdown mmshutdown: Unexpected error from
>   getLocalNodeData: Unknown environmentType .  Return code: 1

logs have this info:

> Mon Feb 15 18:18:34 IST 2016: Node rebooted.  Starting mmautoload...
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. Mon Feb 15
>   18:18:34 IST 2016 mmautoload: GPFS is waiting for daemon network
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. Mon Feb 15
>   18:19:34 IST 2016 mmautoload: GPFS is waiting for daemon network
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. Mon Feb 15
>   18:20:34 IST 2016 mmautoload: GPFS is waiting for daemon network
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. Mon Feb 15
>   18:21:35 IST 2016 mmautoload: GPFS is waiting for daemon network
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. Mon Feb 15
>   18:22:35 IST 2016 mmautoload: GPFS is waiting for daemon network
>   mmautoload: Unable to determine the local node identity. mmautoload:
>   The GPFS environment cannot be initialized. mmautoload: Correct the
>   problem and use mmstartup to start GPFS.

I tried changing the IP to new one, still the same error:

> [root@gpfs1 ~]# mmchnode -N gpfs3 --admin-interface=xx.xx.xx.xx  Mon Feb 15 20:00:05 IST 2016:
>   mmchnode: Processing node gpfs3 mmremote: Unable to determine the
>   local node identity. mmremote: Command failed. Examine previous error
>   messages to determine cause. mmremote: Unable to determine the local
>   node identity. mmremote: Command failed. Examine previous error
>   messages to determine cause. mmchnode: Unexpected error from
>   checkExistingClusterNode gpfs3.  Return code: 0 mmchnode: Command
>   failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is probably to remove the node from the cluster (`mmdelnode`) and then add it back in (`mmaddnode`). You might need to `mmdelnode -f`.

If deleting and adding the node back in is not an option, try giving IBM support a call.